# 404 error (resource not found) uploading to Cloudinary from Filament

Tags: php, laravel, cloudinary, laravel-filament

I'm using Laravel on my website and for the admin panel, I decided to use [Filament](https://filamentphp.com/).

I have a problem that I really can't solve. I've been looking for a solution for about two days.

I set my Laravel storage to Cloudinary in `filesystems.php` and also changed `FILESYSTEM_DISK` in the `.env` file from local to Cloudinary.

```
'cloudinary' => [
    'driver'         => 'cloudinary',
    'api_key'        => env('CLOUDINARY_API_KEY'),
    'api_secret'     => env('CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET'),
    'cloud_name'     => env('CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME'),
    'secure'         => env('CLOUDINARY_SECURE', true),
    'url' => env('CLOUDINARY_URL'),
    'throw' => false,
],
```

And this is the part of my code that is for Filament which is the uploading image part of the form.

```
Section::make('image')->schema([
    FileUpload::make('image')
        ->disk('cloudinary')
        ->required()
        ->image()
        ->maxFiles(1)
        ->label('')
])->collapsible(),
```

When I choose an image to upload and before submitting the form, it successfully uploads the image to Cloudinary in the `livewire` folder that it's made but after submitting the form it throws an exception:

> Resource not found - livewire-tmp/yVYWB1RelRjCXBVeW851JyAuf00ag5-metaMS5qcGc=-.jpg

I also tried to upload to Cloudinary without depending on Filament in another route. It worked perfectly fine. So I think there is a problem with Filament.

I need your help please

Comment: Can any one help me with that?

Comment: It is hard to give you an answer, first you should not post images of error traces, just pull the error stack and post it normally. 
Second, if the upload is working, then there must be another error. You should add all relevant code.

Comment: I don't know which part is causing this error. but as it uploads to Cloudinary after submitting the form I have an error from a file in Cloudinary  Laravel package. I guess Filament cause this error but I'm not sure which part is wrong as I did exactly what Filament documentation says. https://filamentphp.com/docs/2.x/forms/fields#file-upload

Comment: Is there a problem with the way you're naming the file? the error from cloudinary suggests you're trying to load a file with a public_id value of `livewire-tmp/yVYWB1RelRjCXBVeW851JyAuf00ag5-metaMS5qcGc=-.jpg` (including the .jpg), but the public_id shouldn't contain the file extension for images or videos.
Is the file certainly uploaded to Cloudinary at the specified path? or is it slightly different?

Comment: Thanks for answering. Yes you're right. filament at first upload image in a folder called `livewire` on Cloudinary, This problem cause after submitting the form as I don't know what exactly Filament wants to do by requesting to Cloudinary after submitting the form again. Any way, should It be like `livewire-tmp/yVYWB1RelRjCXBVeW851JyAuf00ag5-metaMS5qcGc=-` ? If yes I'm not sure whether I should change a part of a code in Filament.